# Apache Virtual Host doesn't work

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to get Apache Virtual Host to work but it wont catch the domains and goes out on the internet instead.

I've enabled the Virtual Host in the Config file:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "//nas/Web Design/Sites"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@fdn.dk
    DocumentRoot "//nas/Web Design/Sites/Fdn"
    ServerName fdn.dk
    ServerAlias www.fdn.dk
    ErrorLog "logs/fdn/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/fdn/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

http://Localhost works fine but when i type fdn.dk or www.fdn.dk the browser tries to find the site on the internet instead of looking at my local folder.

What is wrong...??
I tried to find a solution on the internet but without luck.

Do I need to change something in the host file ???

Kind Regards
Flemming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add that domain name to `/etc/hosts` file if you are using an operating system that has it.
Or to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` if you are using Windows.

Example of record:
`127.0.0.1 www.fdn.dk`

Comment: Fantastic - it worked!!!

One additional question:
Do I need to add an entry for both fdn.dk and www.fdn.dk or can it be done in one entry??

Comment: yes, you need both

Comment: Great I'll do that.
Thanks.